# pip install - install an specific version python to isolated my environment

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying install an specific version python, to create a project, When I using pip install python2.5 or pip install python2.7 to isolated my environment, throw an error:

(.venv) b3@b3:/media/b3/documents$ pip install python2.5
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python2.5 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python2.5
(.venv) b3@b3:/media/b3/documents$ pip install python2.7
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python2.7 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python2.7

Comment: The error tells you what's wrong. You'll have to do it manually. Maybe it would be easier though to get an older OS distribution, like ten years at least.

Comment: You can't install different versions of Python through pip. Download the source from https://www.python.org/downloads/ - that's pretty isolated. Alternatively, you could use `sudo apt-get` if you're on Linux (which it appears you are). This isn't an isolated version, though.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please format your code properly, use the ``` block code ```. Here for more information https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You could use a Conda isolated environment instead - see https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/